# Unable to import aerospike in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, aerospike

I was trying to import aerospike after downloading it using pip and I am getting this error.
I tried reinstalling the python using homebrew and graphical installer but the result is the same. I am able to import other packages such as numpy.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aerospike.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aerospike.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

on OSX Catalina there are some issues with the default openssl install. Please follow these steps.

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew uninstall openssl; brew uninstall openssl; brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

More details here - https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/86

Answer (score 6):

The Aerospike python client is most likely failing on import because of a missing openssl dependency.

I would recommend installing openssl

```
brew install openssl
```

Then reinstalling the python client with.

```
pip install aerospike --force-reinstall
```

Otherwise you can follow the OSX build instructions here. https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-python/blob/master/BUILD.md#os-x

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me - it's a combination of the solutions written before me (but since we had other things dependent on SSL 1.1.1, we couldn't uninstall it).

```sh
# install latest version of OpenSSL if not already exist
brew install openssl

# install Aerospike client
pip3 install aerospike

# if aerospike does not import, then install an older version of OpenSSL - 1.0.2t
brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

This will alert that:

```
Warning: openssl 1.1.1f is available and more recent than version 1.0.2t.
```

but that is fine since we need an older version in order to use Aerospike.

Then, we can use brew to set it to the older OpenSSL version:

```sh
# switch to the older OpenSSL version we installed
brew switch openssl 1.0.2t

Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t
Opt link created for /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2t
```

This worked for Python 3.7.7 and OS X 10.14.6

P.S:
in some cases this worked, without needing to install OpenSSL 1.0.2t so you might want to try those as well:

```sh
# switch to older OpenSSL in 10.14
brew switch openssl 1.0.2s

# switch to older OpenSSL in 10.15
brew switch openssl 1.0.2q
```